# Custom query parameters format serializer and extractor [JS]

Tags: javascript, json, serialization

I have a JSON object of the type

```
[
  {
    at: "own",
    op: "in_between",
    va: ["str", "jan"]
  },
  {
    a: 'alas',
    op: 'cont',
    va: [10, 20]
  },
  .
  .
  .
]
```

I want to pass this as a GET query parameter. Now I could just stringify it and pass it as something like this

```
?q={"0":{"at":"own","op":"in_between","va":["str","jan"]},"1":{"at":"alas","op":"cont","va":[10,20]}}
```

However I would prefer to serialize it in a different format. Something like

```
q[]=at:"own"|op:"in_between"|va:["str","jan"]&q[]=at:"alas"|op:"cont"|va:[10,20]
```

(I saw a this kind of format being used in Amazon's search filters. Any other format suggestions are welcome. My main goal is to shorten the URL)

So i was able to serialize it by just concatenating to a string

```
let q = "";
data.forEach(function(i) {
  q = q.concat(`q[]=at:"${i.at}"|op:"${i.op}"|va:[${i.val}]&`);
});
return q.slice(0,-1);
```

Similarly I have an extractor

```
let qArray = q.split('&');
let qParse = [];
qArray.forEach(function(i) {
  i = JSON.parse('{' + i.substring(4).split('|').join(',') + '}');
  q.push(i);
});
```

However this only works well for q[1] where q[1]['va'] has an integer array. It needs to also work for q[0] with the string values

Also is there any better way of serializing and extracting it in these kinds of forms?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Don't wanna sound dumb but why do you use a structure like " `{ 0: {}, 1: {}...}` "  instead of juste storing your dictionnaries into an array like `[{...},{...}]` ? Wouldn't it be easier to look at each element this way ?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're not using POST to avoid altogether the problem of URL length?

Comment: @Zyigh you are correct. It's actually like that only i'm just a little tired :) Edited it

Comment: @James I want the link to be sharable

Comment: @JCDenton and what does each dictionary represent ? What's inside of them ? Is it a result of something like "filtering results" or juste the result of the query for filtering ?

Comment: @Zyigh its basically the filter parameters. The query params are auto updated in the URL when they are changed

Comment: @JCDenton I'm not quite an expert about that, but wouldn't csv format work perfectly ? As each dictionnary is the same couldn't your url look like `?q=;at,op,va;own,in_between,[1,2,3];alas,cont,[10,20];...` ? There must be at least 100 000 000 librairies doing that in JavaScript

Comment: Does each request use the same params (at, op, va) repeated?

Comment: @James yes the same params repeat

Answer (score 0):

As said previously in the comments, I was wondering if CSV wouldn't work for what you want. It's kind of easy to parse. Would this work (assuming `filters` is your array) ? :

```
let params = "?q=;at,op,va;";
filters.forEach(function(fil) {
    params += fil.at + "," + fil.op + "," + JSON.stringify(fil.va) + ";";
})
```

If you want to store queries to make percentage, you'd just have to remove first three characters. I'm also supposing that all your dictionnaries follow the same structure. Hope this works for you